# Is it OK to delete displayed_galleries_ from wp_options?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I was finally able to access a problem site's WordPress admin by deleting a ton of transient files via SQL query: DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('*transient*%');
I notice there are even more lines with displayed_galleries_xxxx that I think were from some old plugin. Is it OK to delete them, too?

Comment: [Backup](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Backups) your database and try it. If it goes wrong, restore.

Comment: No it's not ok to delete them until you are sure it's ok.

Comment: Good advice. I backed up and sent the query DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_displayed_galleries_%'); but it didn't delete anything

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this it seems like the 75k + '_displayed_galleries_%' lines in the wp-options was caused by a Statcounter plugin gone wrong, and it is good to delete them.